# How to auto collapse Bootstrap 4 Sidebar for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive, sidebar

This is my current code, I've managed to hide the sidebar with the collapse button, but I want it to  only collapse for small devices, like the bootstrap navbar does.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 px-1 bg-light" id="sidebar">
      <div class="py-2 sticky-top flex-grow-1">
        <div class="nav flex-sm-column">
          <h2 class="text-center">PROFILE</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapse" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapse">Toggle both elements</button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <a href="" class="nav-link">LINK</a>
          <a href="" class="nav-link">LINK</a>
          <a href="" class="nav-link">LINK</a>
          </div>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-9" id="main">
        
          ***PAGE DATA
        
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what you are looking for. What the others have written above will work but it is harder than just using bootstrap classes.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a media query to do this:

```
@media (max-width: 568px) {
  #sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use this it will help solve your problem. You can learn more from here [W3SCHOOLS](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

```
   @media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav {
    width:100%;
  }
  .nav-link {
    width:100%;
    float:none;
  }
}
```